# Merging Many Folders

Tags: vb.net, merge, directory

Let's say I have an installer that has a lot of options, as in,

> [Example]
>
> [ ] Install Mod 1
>
> [ ] Install Mod 2
>
> [ ] Install Mod 3

... and etc, there are a LOT of checkboxes.

Most of these "Mods" have the same folders called "GUI" and "Scripts".

But different file names, now I'm wondering...

Let's say the users selects the Mod 1, 2, and 3.

So 3 mods have to be installed.

Instead of moving file by file (a lot more coding for me), how can I simplify the code where the program just moves the gui and script folders to the "Installation folder", and merges them?

Where it only leave 2 folders gui and scripts, with all the files.

I hope you understood what exactly I meant, if not, here is another example:

> My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(mod1 & "\gui", gamefolder &
> "\gui", true)  My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(mod2 & "\gui",
> gamefolder & "\gui", true)  My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(mod3
> & "\gui", gamefolder & "\gui", true)

Each "Gui" folder has around 5 files (all files have different names)

All I want it to do, is simply merge all of those folders into one gui folder with 15 files.

P.S some gui folders have sub folders!

**EDIT:** What a fail, I just found the solution, I was trying to merge the folders using the code listed above and it wasn't working, then I noticed that I got the directory wrong (facepalm) it all works!!!

But now I have a different problem... Why isn't my VB.Net not telling me that there was an error in finding the directory O_o?

I'm not using the "Try" method.

Comment: A VB.NET answer will not make you happy if you are using VBA and vice versa

Comment: I'm using Visual Basic 2012... I thought VBA was Vb.net O_o ?

Comment: the tags have extensive explantions

Comment: Erm.. Mk, I removed the "VBA".